# How to loop to find child elements in Selenium xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I wanted to scrape names from all the reviews of a certain product but I am getting stuck on how to loop over each review block to get its child names.

My code so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException


chromedriver = "path to chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

url = "https://www.amazon.com/Arti-Cipes-Electric-Cosmetic-Automatic-Machine-Spinner/product-reviews/B08QMKN8Z8/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews"
driver.get(url)
    
item_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="a-row product-title"]/h1/a').text
    
name_row = []
for review in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"]'):
    if review.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]//span[@class="a-profile-name"]') :
        name_row.append(review.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]//span[@class="a-profile-name"]').text)
    else:
        name_row.append("None")
        
    # Loop if next page button is there
    while True:
        try: 
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="a-last"]/a'):
                url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="a-last"]/a').get_attribute('href')
            else:
                break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break
        
        driver.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
        
        for review in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"]'):
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]//span[@class="a-profile-name"]'):
                name_row.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]//span[@class="a-profile-name"]').text)
            else:
                name_row.append("None")
        
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': name_row})
df.to_csv(item_name + '.csv', index=False)
    
driver.close()
```

My result is just first name of each page repeated by the amount of reviews on each page and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Is there any way to call something on review inside the for loop to access its name xpath and whatnot?

```
for review in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"]'):
    a = review.text
    #some way to call review's name xpath? 
    #this returns the whole text files of the reviews on the page
```

Side note:
I am aware that I can just put all of them in a list by finding elements of the xpath of the names but I realized some other item's reviews do not have names and when I get other data like ratings, it ends up messing up the corresponding order of the ratings to the names when put into dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have quite a mess inside a loop.
So in your case you loop over reviews and for each step of the loop you are getting first name of the reviewer all the time.

In xpath if you start search with `//` it will search from the beginning of the document.

What you would like to do here would be:

```py
for review in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]/div[@data-hook="review"]'):
    if review.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="a-profile-name"]') :
        name_row.append(review.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="a-profile-name"]').text)
    else:
        name_row.append("None")
```

As you can see `.//` would start the search from within the review HTML.

Second thing is you have a loop to go over pages inside the loop for checking the reviews, and then another loop again for reviews.

Basically you could right away find all names that you need with only one search with xpath.

Here is working example:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
# Set driver to wait up to 3 seconds for the elements to appear if we try to find them
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

url = "https://www.amazon.com/Arti-Cipes-Electric-Cosmetic-Automatic-Machine-Spinner/product-reviews/B08QMKN8Z8/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews"
driver.get(url)
    
item_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="a-row product-title"]/h1/a').text
    
name_row = []

while True:
    try:
        # Get all name rows
        name_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]//span[@class="a-profile-name"]')
        # Get text from each span element
        names = [row.text for row in name_rows]
        name_row.extend(names)
        
        next_page_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="a-last"]/a')
        url = next_page_button.get_attribute('href')
        driver.get(url)
        
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
        
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': name_row})
df.to_csv(item_name + '.csv', index=False)

driver.close()
```

There is also room for optimisation because you could use only `requests` and `lxml` library since there is no real need to use selenium but this is another scope of the problem